# Gating access to large corridor

Tags: fence, garage-door, gates

I would like control access to a "corridor" as shown here:

[image]

Photo shows front side of corridor, back side is similar.  The corridor is slightly over 2 cars wide.  This is a commercial building and customer vehicles must occasionally traverse the corridor to gain access to second building on the other side of the corridor.  The gating mechanism should be as effective as a garage door / fence to keep out cars / people / dogs.

I must decide on a gating mechanism:

1. Garage-door type gate
2. Fence style
3. Other??

The goal is to eventually automate and keep out unauthorized vehicles / people from traversing.  To constrain the problem, I can not consider a guard, or expensive ($3K or more) ideas.

Questions

- Can a custom garage door be sized to fit the corridor?
- **Would the garage door be more reliable \ simpler to maintain than a sliding fence?**
- Have I missed any other cost-effective \ practical \ modern gating mechanism possibilities?

Any experience gained from lessons-learned / pitfalls to avoid are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on automating it, you should go with a garage door. Standard sizes would be 10', 12', 14', 16' wide by 7' or 8' high.  The sides and top can be framed in with 2x6es and covered in white PVC board to make up any size difference.

Comment: Commercial garage doors come bigger. Problem might be the weather exposure of the opening mechanism.